# Monitor Disk via SNMP polling

Tags: linux, network-attached-storage, snmp

I'm using SNMP (polling not traps) to monitor a Snap Server with MIB-II (RFC 1213). Since there is no specialized MIB for this device I am stuck via standard MIB-II.  My main goal is to poll the disks and make sure they are not disconnected and mounted. I'm really just looking for best practice here since I'm not much of a Linux admin.

The snap server has a RAID 1.

My plan is to monitor /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc ect. Starting at OID: .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1552 and up. Right now the string just returns /dev/sda/ which I told my software is the proper string to return. If disk 0 goes down I assume it will no longer return /dev/sda for .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1552 at least this is what I'm hoping.

Can anyone confirm my suspicion on this one? I don't really have an easy way of testing this one without physically building a PC and unplugging a drive as the linux boxes I have access to are in production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check the [Host Resources MIB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2790). The OID you are mentioning is the `hrDeviceDescr` field. If you look further in that MIB, you can see the `hrDeviceStatus`, which is an integer defined as follows:

> The current operational state of the device described by this row of the table.  A value unknown(1)
> indicates that the current state of the device is unknown.  running(2) indicates that the device is up
> and running and that no unusual error conditions are known.  The warning(3) state indicates that agent
> has been informed of an unusual error condition by the operational software (e.g., a disk device driver)
> but that the device is still 'operational'.  An example would be a high number of soft errors on a disk.
> A value of testing(4), indicates that the device is not available for use because it is in the testing
> state. The state of down(5) is used only when the agent has been informed that the device is not
> available for any use.

Thus, you should probably better monitor the following OID: `.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.5.1552`.

Comment: Wow, thank you... it's amazing what you find when you sit down for a minute and read. Thanks again!